# Zoom in closer picture when Particular image been Touched

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-ndk

Thanks in advance.I am doing an application similar to Coverflow example. It looks like this.

http://www.somesoundswelike.com/wp-content/CoverFlowScreenSnapz001.jpg. When particular image

been clicked, that image should be zoomed closer and viewed in full screen. Please guide me

how to proceed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zooming using the gl_Position and use MvpMatrix which u frame and create the far near effect which looks like zoomin and zoomout. I guess you can proceed with it

You can proceed with this [code](http://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/books/openglr_es_20_programming_guide_sample.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are probably going to use openGL-es for the zooming in/out and swiping. So what you would do is draw the images as textures onto a surface and manipulate the surface size and distance.